# How do I read a C# generated Protobuf file in a C++ Windows Phone 8.1 Background Task

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, windows-phone-8.1, background-task

C++ is really not my area so apologies if this should be obvious.

I have a C# generated protobuf-net message that I want to rehydrate into my model in a C++ background task on Windows Phone 8.1 (probably on a raw notification) so I can update some Live Tiles.

I've looked at the [Updating a tile from a background task sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Updating-a-tile-from-a-e0e492df) and I can follow how that works and I should be able to figure out how to access the file system from the [File access sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/File-access-sample-d723e597). Where I'm stumped is how I should go about loading the pbf file into a model I can pass into the Tile Update routines.

Obviously I could do this in C# but the advice seems to be that the memory footprint is lower in C++

[Update] Steps so far

1. Generate a .proto file from the C# Version using Serializer.GetProto with my C# Model
2. Download the protoc compiler from [Google](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/downloads/list)
3. Use protoc -I="C:\temp" --cpp_out="C:\temp" "C:\temp\Model.proto" to generate a compiled model, this took some iteration and tweaking of the .proto file ([.proto Documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding))
4. Create a C++ DLL in Visual Studio
5. Add the .pb.h and .pb.cc files generated in step 3

I'm now stumped (told you C++ wasn't my thing), obviously I have to include the protobuf library in some way. Is the best option to include all the source files one by one or is there a better way?

Comment: Do you have a .proto to feed into the c++ protoc? For simple c# models you can generate the model via Serializer.GetProto

Comment: Not yet, my model is mostly primitives with the odd dictionary and son nullable types. Will Serializer.GetProto work?

Comment: it should do; thigs like DateTime, TimeSpan and Guide are awkward though. I recommend simple types like integers and blobs when working cross-platform

Comment: Cool, looks like it works, I think the only interesting parts are DateTimeOffSet, KeyValuePair (from the dictionaries) and a few Enums. I'd prefer not to change my model if possible to avoid breaking older clients. Any advice? Is there an equivalent to the  Surrogate pattern on the C++ side. Is it the Google C++ lib I should be looking at?

Comment: Could I make the C++ version ignore the DateTimeOffSetSurrgogates? Then I could add a primitive equivalent for the C++ side?

Comment: did you mean c# in the first line? And: no

Comment: I've got a .proto that compiles into the .pb.cc and .pb.h files now (thanks for your help so far by the way). Am I right in thinking this should work and send the Dattime as a string?   message DateTimeOffsetSurrogate {
   required string DateTimeString = 1;
}

Comment: possibly; hard to tell without a detailed look